# Why aren't the percentages I'm using for padding in my CSS working?

Tags: html, css, padding

I am using percentages instead of pixels for padding in my CSS, but they aren't working.

```
.menu li a{ padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;}
```

I want to use percentages to make the menu section responsive in all dimensions. How could I achieve this?

Comment: How is it not working? Could you give a small working example. [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would work well. :)

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/Am3hx/ can you push your code.

Comment: Please wait for 5 mins. I'll provide you the code in fiddle

Comment: Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DrPQe/1/

Comment: @designersvsoft The paddings work fine for me. I changed them to 20%, 50%, etc., and they behaved like they should. :/

Comment: increase the padding...it's working dude..may overridden from somewhere

Comment: On my browser, your menu item (ul>li) width is only 27px. Now 5% of 27px is only about 1.3px. You can hardly notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is technically fine. It might be getting overridden - but that is just one possibility. It will also depend on the width of the parent element.

Comment: I'll give the width to the parent ul element. It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now define pixel value in your anchor link

replace `%` in `pixel value`

```
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrPQe/2/)***

Answer (score 0):

The % is working here but your anchor tag inside 'li' element don't have any width specified, that is why you are not able to see the effect.

If you want to see the effect, try by placing "width: 100px" in "#coolMenu li a" and you will see immediate effect of % padding.